# How can you supress hive column names printing to CLI?

Tags: linux, hadoop, hive, hiveql

I have so many columns in my hive table that it is causing my text editor to crash upon the completion of my jobs.  I am hoping there is a

```
set hive.exec.showheaders=false
```

I have looked through the hive JIRA but can't fine a way to change any type of setting.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

set the property below to false.

```
hive> set hive.cli.print.header=false;
```